# expanding mean on a groupby object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks something like:

```
Name  Col1 Col2 Col3 DownIndicator 
A                     0
A                     1
B                     0
C                     0    
C                     1
C                     1
```

I want to create   column that shows expanding mean for the DownIndicator Column

So the the output desired would be

```
Name  Col1 Col2 Col3 DownIndicator MeanDown
A                     0             0
A                     1             0.5
B                     0             0
C                     0             0
C                     1             0.5
C                     1             0.66
```

Could you please help.
I am looking at expanding_mean, but unable to apply it in practice

Comment: You mean 'rolling mean'. Please see all the existing duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Expanding.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Expanding.mean.html) with `groupby`, but because is create `MultiIndex` is necessary remove first level by `reset_index(level=0, drop=True)`:

```
df['new'] = (df.groupby('Name')['DownIndicator']
               .expanding()
               .mean()
               .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
print (df)
  Name  DownIndicator       new
0    A              0  0.000000
1    A              1  0.500000
2    B              0  0.000000
3    C              0  0.000000
4    C              1  0.500000
5    C              1  0.666667
```